# Extract read/write set of state variable from a smart contract

Tags: solidity, state-variable, leveldb

Is there any way that i can extract read and write set of Ethereum state from a smart contract? To be specific, I want to figure out what this function read and write from Ethereum state.

My one idea is analyzing AST created when compiling the solidity code, but is there any other way or simper way of doing this?